# RabbitMQ MQTT send to a specified subscriber

Tags: java, rabbitmq, mqtt, spring-amqp

Firstly, I will explain how I need to use MQTT.
My backend is made up of several *micro-services* made with **Spring-boot**. The consumers of my *apis* are applications *web* and *mobile*, for the update of mobiles we used the **onesignal** but it is not able to meet us in certain features like and positioning in the map in "*real time* ", after a study we saw that the most used today is MQTT for mobiles, for that we intend to use **RabbitMQ MQTT**, since we already have several implementations using Rabbit.
But here comes my great doubt, how do I get the *producer* (platform) to send the information to the correct *subscribe* (app), because all the examples I found, none made this ID.

I know that when the application connects to Rabbit it creates a *Queue* temporary, and when the MQTT service goes up it associates with a Rabbit *Exchange*. my problem is only to identify the final destination even.

Comment: Did you perhaps try assigning the queues subscriber ids...? Something like described in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27228957/how-subscribe-in-an-rabbitmq-queue-with-mqtt-paho

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to publish a message to a specific client in Mosquitto MQTT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42265001/how-to-publish-a-message-to-a-specific-client-in-mosquitto-mqtt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to look here [How to publish a message to a specific client in Mosquitto MQTT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42265001/how-to-publish-a-message-to-a-specific-client-in-mosquitto-mqtt).

The same is applied for RabbitMQ MQTT support.

So, or you need *filtering* on the client side, or consider to have MQTT topics for each subscriber.

Comment: This is effectively a link only answer, you should have probably marked the question as a duplicate